# What should be correct autocomplete for username = email?

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete

I see [in the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofilling-form-controls%3A-the-autocomplete-attribute) that I can have `autocomplete` either equal to `username` or `email` on an input field.

In my case, username is actually the user's email.

What is the best `autocomplete` to use on my username `input` field in this case to maximize compatibility with password managers?

Comment: As a follow-up, what value should be used on the "register" page? I feel like maybe use "email" for registering and "username" for logging in.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For a login form I think it's better to use `autocomplete="username"` for a username field, even if it is expected to be an email address.

I have no hard evidence for this but I expect this would be more friendly to password managers.

[This article](https://hiddedevries.nl/en/blog/2018-01-13-making-password-managers-play-ball-with-your-login-form) suggests the same.

[A design document from Chromium aimed at developers](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/form-styles-that-chromium-understands) also seems to suggest the same, and I quote from that:

> ```
> <form id="login" action="login.php" method="post">
>   <input id="emailfield" type="text" value="me@example.test" autocomplete="username">
>   <input type="password" autocomplete="current-password">
>   <input type="submit" value="Sign In!">
> </form>
> ```

For a registration form, `autocomplete="email"` *may* make more sense.

Answer (score -3):

I ended up researching quite a bit, and found out these conclusions to be true: [Angular forms and password managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911864/angular-forms-and-password-managers/53956890#53956890), if anyone ends up googling here.

Comment: I don't see how the answer you link to actually answers your question.

Comment: The end goal was to maximize compatibility with password managers, not so much a question about standards.

Comment: The link does not even relate to the question

Comment: See points 3, 4 & 5 in the linked answer, you'll see it is related to the question.

Answer (score -5):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you can also set the **autocomplete** to just **on** or **off**.
That will make it so it recommends whatever the user last submitted through the input field with no guidance for the browser.
Additionally, I'm linking you to the page where you can see all the values you can use with **autocomplete**, hope it helps.

ref.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Comment: Yeah thanks. The question is more of usage: as both username and email would apply in my case, what is the best value for autocomplete? I see in the standard that putting the two of them seems not permitted. I wonder how people usually go with that.

Comment: I think you should put email, since username usually refers to a nickname or an account name chosen by the user.

Comment: I would have thought "username" was more password-manager-friendly, but I have no evidence for that.